# WxPython ListCtrl index 0 item non editable

Tags: wxpython, listctrl

```
self.testParameters = self.testParameterListCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT      |wx.LC_HRULES | wx.LC_VRULES | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
self.testParameters.InsertColumn(0, "Parameter", wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTER, -1)
self.testParameters.InsertColumn(1, "Value", wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTER, -1)
self.testParameters.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT, self.onModifyTestParameter )

for parameter, value in self.keywordArgs.iteritems():
        self.testParameters.InsertStringItem(index, parameter, 0)
        self.testParameters.SetStringItem(index, 1, str(value))
        if parameter in self.workloadTests.values():
            self.testParameters.SetStringItem(index, 1, self.testWorkload.GetValue())
        # Cell Colors
        if (index % 2): 
            self.testParameters.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, self.listBGColor_1)
        else:
            self.testParameters.SetItemBackgroundColour(index, self.listBGColor_2)
        index += 1
```

In this code, I want disable '0' index "parameter" as non editable listCtrl and '1' index 'value" as editable listCtrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using an EditableListCtrl from

```
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
```

Create a class for the mix in

```
class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.TextEditMixin):
    # TextEditMixin allows any column to be edited other than those specifically vetoed
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, style)
        listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self)
```

define your listctrl as editable

```
self.listCtrl = EditableListCtrl(my_panel1, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL|wx.LC_VRULES, size=(1145,285))
```

Then bind for the vetoing of certain items: `self.listCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_LABEL_EDIT, self.OnVetoItems)`

define your veto function

```
def OnVetoItems(self, event): 
    if event.m_itemIndex == 0:
        event.Veto()
        return
```

Note Columns can be veto'd as well using `event.m_col` and checking against the number of the column in the listctrl

Comment: if event.m_col == 0:
        event.Veto()
        return  By using this code I am able to edit column 0,But I don't want edit the 0 column(i.e Readable )

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Put a print command in your veto function, to test that you are executing the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using `wx.ListCtrl`s is almost always a pain. I recommend you try using `ObjectListView` instead

[General usage](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/gettingStarted.html).

[Cell editing](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/cellEditing.html#cell-editing-label)

Example:

```
#!python3
import wx
from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn

random_objects = [
    {"parameter": "Test", "value": "1"},
    {"parameter": "Test2", "value": "2"}
]


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent=None, title="OLV Test")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.olv = ObjectListView(parent=self, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN, sortable=True,
                                  useAlternateBackColors=False, cellEditMode=ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_DOUBLECLICK)
        self.olv.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn(title="Parameter", valueGetter="parameter", isSpaceFilling=True, isEditable=False),
            ColumnDefn(title="Value", valueGetter="value", isSpaceFilling=True)
        ])

        get_button = wx.Button(self, label="Print objects")

        top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)  # Root sizer
        olv_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)  # For the ObjectListView
        button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        olv_sizer.Add(self.olv, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_TOP, 5)
        button_sizer.Add(get_button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)

        top_sizer.Add(olv_sizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        top_sizer.Add(button_sizer, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(top_sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler=self.get_objects, source=get_button)

        self.olv.SetObjects(random_objects)

    def get_objects(self, event):
        for item in self.olv.GetObjects():
            print("Parameter: {param}".format(param=item['parameter']))
            print("Value: {val}".format(val=item['value']))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wx_app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

When the user edits the list, the values in `random_objects` update as well, so you can actually use that instead of `self.olv.GetObjects()` if you'd like.